# I want R to prompt for entering filename & location while exporting my as output a pdf

Tags: r

I am writing a function of simple linear regression. However I'm stuck at exporting the plot and summary(lm()) as pdf file. I don't want to prename the pdf file using pdf("name") since I will be using this function repeatedly.

```
pdf() 
paste(print(summary(e)),"\n","\n","\n") 
plot(a ~ b,ylab="Dependent Variable",xlab="Independent Variable", 
col="purple",main = "Regression") 
abline(lm(a ~ b)) 
dev.off()
```

Please help me in finding the right way to
1) make R to prompt for filename before writing it to a pdf file.
2) write both plot and text to a pdf (in my case, the summary of lm())

TIA

Comment: look into `?readline`

Comment: thank you, i learnt a new command. but, i want r to prompt a pop-up asking to give a filename & specify path to export the o/p as pdf file.

Comment: Then study the `shiny` package. I see this as two questions (and multipart questions are deprecated), both likely to have been asked and answered already on SO. I see the two tags as being unlikely to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the output file using `file.choose`. To get the text, you may want to make a blank plot and then use `text` to display the desired output. 
Here is a small example.

```
## Set up file for output
pdf(file.choose())

## Scatterplot with regression line
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species])
LM = lm(iris[,4:3])
abline(LM)

## Now add the summary text
SUM = capture.output(LM)
SUM = paste(SUM, collapse="\n")
plot(0:10, type = "n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
text(1, 8, SUM, adj=0, family="mono")

## close file
dev.off()
```

The output file looked good to me, but the text is just an image of text, not text that you can cut and paste.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out, I mean it. I'll be using these in the function.

Comment: @AbhilashManikanta if you like the answer given above, please accept it.